# Representation of $S_3$ using Galois group of cubic polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory, galois-theory

I'm studying Lang's Algebra and the first exercise of representation of finite groups is about the representation of $S_3$:

> Let $S_3$ be the symmetric group on 3 elements,
> (a) Show that there are three conjugacy classes.
> (b) There are two characters of dimension 1, on $S_3 / A_3$.
> (c) Let $d_i(i=1,2,3)$ be the dimensions of the irreducible characters. Since $\sum d_i^2=6$, the third irreducible character has dimension 2. Show that the third representation can be realized by considering a cubic equation $X^3+a X+b=0$, whose Galois group is $S_3$ over a field $k$. Let $V$ be the $k$ vector space generated by the roots. Show that this space is 2-dimensional and gives the desired representation, which remains irreducible after tensoring with $k^{\mathrm{a}}$.
> (d) Let $G=S_3$. Write down an idempotent for each one of the simple components of $\mathbf{C}[G]$. What is the multiplicity of each irreducible representation of $G$ in the regular reprepesentation on C $G]$ ? $G$

In the third point I chose the equation $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has Galois group $S_3$ (see https://planetmath.org/galoisgroupofacubicpolynomial for a reference) which has
roots $\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}\omega,\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$. However I cannot see how the vector space $V$ generated by these roots over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$-dimensional since for that to be the case it would have to be that one of the roots is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Maybe we have to take $\mathbb{R}$ as the field?
Nonetheless if $V$ is the correct vector space than my guess is that the representation is  the one induced by the action of the Galois group $G$
$$
G\times V\rightarrow V\\
(\sigma,\xi_i)\mapsto \sigma(\xi_i)
$$
where $\xi_i$ with $i=1,2,3$ are the roots of the polynomial. Is this the correct representation? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the Vieta formulas, the sum of the roots of a polynomial equals the negative of the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$, which is $0$ in this case. In particular, they are not linearly independent.

Comment: Oh because in this case the complex roots are conjugate and therefore$ \sqrt[3]{2}\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$ is not linearly independent with $\sqrt[3]{2}$?

Comment: Please do no use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the three roots of $x^3+ax+b$ are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in  k^a$ (which I assume is notation for the algebraic closure of $k$).  By the Vieta formulas, we have that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$ (as well as $\alpha\beta\gamma=-b$ and $\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=a$).  Therefore, $V=\operatorname{span}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\operatorname{span}(\alpha,\beta)$ is at most two dimensional.  However, if it were only one dimensional, so that $\beta=p\alpha, \gamma=q\alpha$ for some $p,q\in k$, then we would have $\alpha^3=-b/pq$ and $\alpha^2=a/(p+q+pq)$.  In particular, $\alpha^2, \alpha^3\in k$, and hence $\alpha\in k$, contradicting irreducibility of the polynomial.

However, there is still more work to do, as that only establishes that the vector space $V$ is two dimensional, but not that it is irreducible as a representation.  For that you can use the assumption that the Galois group is $S_3$. The action is the one you wrote.